# PHP executes but doesnt execute SQL update correctly

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a table which displays 
-Staff ID (Primary Key)
-Staff Name
-Staff Position

All the data loads in to my grid, the grid has an update button witch should let me to update it but it returns original result after clicking update.

[image: Example Here]

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$conn){
die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("pizza_shop",$conn);


if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'update'){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE staff SET StaffName='$_POST[staffname]', Position='$_POST[staffposition]' WHERE StaffID='$_POST[hiddenid]'";
mysql_query($UpdateQuery);

}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM staff";
$myData = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Staff Name<th>
<th>Staff Position<th>
</tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
echo "<form action=@edit_staff.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name =staffname value=" . $record['StaffName'] ." </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name =staffposition value=" . $record['Position'] ." </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hiddenid value=" . $record['StaffID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name = update values=Update" . "</td>";
echo "</form>";
}

echo "</table>";
$conn = null;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not use depricated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO with prepared statement. Also you have to check for errors.

Comment: Are you sure that `if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'update')` this condition is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your update query from

```
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE staff SET StaffName='$_POST[staffname]', Position='$_POST[staffposition]' WHERE StaffID='$_POST[hiddenid]'";
```

to

```
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE staff SET StaffName='".$_POST['staffname']."', Position='".$_POST['staffposition']."' WHERE StaffID='".$_POST['hiddenid']."'";
```

What you were doing is `$_POST[staffname]` which must be like as `$_POST['staffname']` and always try to check using `error_reporting(E_ALL)` function and need to check that your values are set or not

Comment: i changed around and still not working, i added in a error collector and all that came up was this  "Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\@edit_staff.php on line 10"

Comment: Yes you were using deprecated `mysql` version you need to use `mysqli` or `PDO` you can check on [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)  or [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp). These are links where you can find how to implement `mysqli` instead of `mysql`